# Firebase Api Key is not working for iOS only

Tags: php, android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notification using firebase in php. My code is working fine for android but not working for ios device.

And I am getting success:1 for both cases.

**Here is my code**

```
<?php 
$path_to_firebase_cm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array('registration_ids' => $token,
                        'data' =>  array('title'=>'Title',
                                         'body'=>$message['message'],
                                         'image'=>$imagepath,
                                         'priority'=>'high'
                                         )
                        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key=AIzaSyBiOCXbU7roG59_**********vWa4Xc' ,
            'Content-Type:application/json'
        );      
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_firebase_cm); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
?>
```

**And response is**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [multicast_id] => 8.5168949472892E+18
    [success] => 1
    [failure] => 0
    [canonical_ids] => 0
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [message_id] => 0:1493801065120413%2d69fd2bf9fd7ecd
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You are getting same response for Android & iOS as a success message. Please check you iOS app whether all the settings have been made to receive notification.

Comment: Okay, But I am getting notification from firebase console @Gagan_iOS

Comment: Okay, but are you aware about iOS code? I think might be possible APNS is working fine but due to some iOS code error, notification is not visible. There are many conditions in iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Delete app from iphone and install again, After that you will get new firebase token try to send push again.
Debug this first from php side they are sending push on newer device token.